# Recuperar datos en Mysql

Tags: mysql, mysqli

tengo una tabla en mi bd en donde al superar la cantidad permitida que tiene el tipo INT, automaticamente me guarda el número   **2147483647** que corresponde al valor máximo permitido en mi campo "telefono"

Tengo aprox 80 regitros pero en la columna "telefono" están estos números (2147483647); existe alguna manera de mostrar los datos reales digitados por los usuarios?

Ya cambié el tipo de dato de la columna "telefono" y ya me guarda bien, pero los anteriores no sé como verlos.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si, en todos los registros te aparece el mismo numero es porque se creo mal el procedimiento para ingresarlos a la base de datos y no hay manera de saber cual era el anterior ya que si se pudiese, sería otra base de datos o sea tendríamos duplicada toda la información, con lo que ya esta base no se justificaría.

Comment: @rpaillao en realidad si que se puede, siempre y cuando tengas activado el log binario. Para comprobar que lo tienes activado has ``show variables like 'log_bin';``

Comment: @JavierG.Raya gracias eso no lo sabía, saludos.

Comment: De nada @rpaillao :-)

Comment: @rpaillao hay un [chat de MySQL](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136425/stack-overflow-en-espanol-mysql) sobre algunas preguntas y respuestas por si te quieres meter :-)

Comment: NO por favor no.. el telefono no es un numero, por mas que este compuesto de numeros!!!!!! es un varchar.. cambia el tipo de columna, ya!!!!!!